# MassTransit RabbitMQ moving half of Consumed messages on Error Queue to Error_Skipped Queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am trying to move messages from and Error Queue back to the Queue that it originated from.
To do this I created a Consumer on the Error Queue and then published it to the Required Queue.
When I try this then half of the Consumed Messages get published but the other half get sent to the Error_Skipped Queue.

I have tried many things without success, so it's probably something simple that I am missing.

Here are samples of my code:

```
public class ClaimsMessage
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public bool Handled { get; set; }
}

public class ClaimsMessageErrorConsumer : IConsumer<Fault<ClaimsMessage>>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Fault<ClaimsMessage>> context)
    {
        try
        {
            await context.Publish<ClaimsMessage>(context.Message.Message);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string error = e.Message;
        }
    }
}

public static IBusControl CreateClaimsErrorConsumerBus(string endPoint)
{
    var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h =>
        {
            h.Username("guest");
            h.Password("guest");
        });

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, endPoint, e =>
        {
            e.Consumer(() => new ClaimsMessageErrorConsumer());
        });
    });
    return busControl;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using [a shovel?](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html)

Comment: I have looked at a Shovel. But it is a bit basic. 
I am wanting to add rules, that will allow us to move only certain messages back again and the rest at a later stage.

Comment: May be try on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/masstransit-discuss)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are moving messages from an error queue back to the processing queue, you should not be calling `Publish` -- this will resend the message to all subscribers. You already know the queue names, so send the messages directly back to the queue. What you're seeing is that you've created a consumer on the error queue, which created an exchange binding for that message.

So, do this instead:

```
sbc.ReceiveEndpoint("input_error", x =>
{
    // this prevents extra message bindings from being created
    x.BindMessageExchanges = false;

    x.Consumer<MyMover>(() => new MyMover(inputQueueAddress);
});

public class MyMover : 
    IConsumer<ClaimsMessage>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ClaimsMessage> context)
    {
        try
        {
            var endpoint = await context.GetSendEndpoint(_inputQueueAddress);
            await endpoint.Send<ClaimsMessage>(context.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string error = e.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

For extra credit, copy over the original message headers so the fidelity of the message is retained.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
Unfortunately it still does the same and one message gets put on the Claims Queue and another on the Claims_error_skipped queue.
I didn't copy over the headers though. Do you think that could be causing it?

Comment: Hi Chris. 
I have created an example project that can be downloaded here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0FYiKs0DMyrYTJfZTcxdVlKSDg/view?usp=sharing[link]
It includes step by step instructions on how I replicated it.
I could very well be missing something but I have read through the documentation quite extensively.

Comment: You should be consuming the original message if you're reading from the error queue, not the Fault<T>. You've essentially created an additional consumer binding on your error queue for Fault<T>, which is going to get the published fault in addition to the original message moved from the queue. Consume T instead, and clean up the bindings in RMQ and you're all set.

Comment: Hi Chris. 
Thank you very much for the reply. 
That worked perfectly and by consuming the actual message type and not the fault worked perfectly. 
Maybe it might be a good idea to update the documentation:
http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/usage/exceptions.html[link]

I appreciate your help.
Keep well

Comment: Sorry here is the correct URL:
http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/usage/exceptions.html